# Using ClickOnce to run a program, not install it

Tags: c#, clickonce

I would like my ClickOnce project to run immediately without installing the game seeing as it is only a simple "showcase"-game and I really don't want to force the moderators to have to uninstall it from the Control Panel afterwards.

Comment: xcopy deploy it, not clickonce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ClickOnce is designed for installing and streamlining future updates of your application. If your wanting someone to just open your application w/ out installing it, just give them your exe. (Assuming you don't have dlls...If you do, then include them too).

You can find them in your project folder\Debug or \Release (depending on which you have compiled).

Answer (score 2):

In visual studio, select the option to have the application available online only.  Then, when launching, the application will be downloaded fresh each time and not installed locally.

Is there a specific reason you are using ClickOnce?

Comment: It actually DOES install the application locally if you set it to "online-only". It just requires that the user be able to access the deployment server in order to run the application, and if any of the files have changed, it downloads new copies of them.